# Inconsistency between Field Dependency values and Picklist values salesforce

Tags: apex, dependent-picklist, field-dependencies

In the field dependency mappings, there are few values which doesn't match with the actual field's picklist values. For instance, There's a picklist called MyDependent__c and the values which we have in that picklist are Dep1,Dep2,Dep3. But when I see the field Dependency Mappings - I could see Dep1, Dependent2, Dep3.

When I tried exploring the picklist values thru schema methods found that even in the debug statement, it shows Dep1, Dependent2, Dep3 but Dependent2 is not there in the picklist values and there is no inactive value in the picklist.

Any thoughts?

Comment: MyDependent__c is a global picklist?

Comment: No, it is not a Global picklist.

Comment: Are you sure its not just the picklist entry 'value vs api name' showing up as difference?

Comment: At the custom field 'MyDependent__c' picklist level,  one of the picklist value is Dep2, and  api value as dep2. But when I use Schema method to print all picklist value, I see  picklist value 'Dependent2' with same api name dep2.